# List of valid characters for the fragment identifier in an URL?

Tags: fragment-identifier

I'm using the fragment identifier to create a permalink for AJAX events in my web app [similar to this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139539/url-fragment-identifier-simplify-state-handling-javascript).  Something like:

```
http://www.myapp.com/calendar#filter:year/2010/month/5
```

I've done quite a bit of searching but can't find a list of valid characters for the fragment idenitifer.  The [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_8) doesn't offer anything.

Do I need to encode the characters the same as the URL in has in general?

There doesn't seem to be any good information on this anywhere.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

See the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

```
fragment    = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"    
unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
                 / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

So you can use `!`, `$`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `;`, `=`, something matching `%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}`, something matching `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, `-`, `.`, `_`, `~`, `:`, `@`, `/`, and `?`

Comment: Perfect, I was looking for that in the RFC but couldn't seem to find the right clause.  Thanks.

Comment: @Artefacto, So does it mean that a "%" is **not** allowed everywhere, but **only** allowed when two valid characters follow it?

Comment: @Pacerier yes, `%` is only allowed as an escape character. Use `%25` to encode a single `%`.

Comment: The back / forward button doesn't work with fragment identifiers that have a colon in spite of the RFC stating that its a valid character.

Comment: Wow! Would be probably easier to tell what ascii characters *cannot* be used!

Comment: In case anyone wants a quick and dirty sanitizer like I did:
`myFragment.replace(/(?=((?:[\!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=a-zA-Z0-9\-._~:@\/?]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*))\1./g, "$1-");`
Replace the - in the "$1-" with the desired placeholder char

Comment: So... basically base 81. Not a clean way to use that...

Answer (score 32):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5:

```
fragment    = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
```

and

```
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
```

So, combined, the fragment *cannot* contain `#`, a raw `%`, `^`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `\`, `"`, `<` and `>` according to the RFC.

Comment: Thanks.  Gave the answer to Artefacto since he was a hair faster but gave you +1 for the response.

Comment: I suppose you're missing non-printable ASCII characters and non-ascii characters.

Comment: Seems that you forgot ``VERTICAL BAR (|)`` and ``GRAVE ACCENT (`)`` and ``SPACE ( )`` in the not-list. So the full list of printable (7-bit) US-ASCII characters in the not-list is: ``"#%< >[\]^`{|}``

Answer (score 2):

One other RFC speak of that: [RFC-1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-5)

```
URL schemeparts for ip based protocols:
HTTP

httpurl        = "http://" hostport [ "/" hpath [ "?" search ]]
hpath          = hsegment *[ "/" hsegment ]
hsegment       = *[ uchar | ";" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" ]
search         = *[ uchar | ";" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" ]
```