# is it valid to use only digits as URI fragment identifier?

Tags: fragment-identifier

Is a link like this valid?

http://some.server/some/path#123

According to ["List of valid characters for the fragment identifier in an URL?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849756/list-of-valid-characters-for-the-fragment-identifier-in-an-url) answers, it should be valid. However, APT parser [complains](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JXR-87) that this kind of link is not valid.

These links are generated by [JXR](http://maven.apache.org/jxr/) and I wonder if JXR should be fixed or is APT parser broken (APT is used by [Maven site plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/)).

Comment: Remember that an `id` attribute in HTML [must](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name) begin with a letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That link is invalid for html/xml documents. Fragment identifiers refer to `id` or `name` attributes of tags.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name

Comment: according to your description, the link itself is valid; however, on an HTML/XML page it cannot refer to a document fragment because fragment IDs must begin with a letter. If that URL would refer to some other type of content (that allows such fragment IDs), it would be perfectly OK.

Comment: You are right, according to [rfc3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) the fragment's format depends on the media type used. I edited the answer to male it more specific.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth. I have noticed this years ago and filed a bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JXR-87
Ridiculously, this is a one line to fix.