# Invalid quotes in URL

Tags: url, url-encoding, w3c-validation, double-quotes

On our website, we are using JSON in `location.hash`. That means we need to use quotes in the URL as for instance:

```
https://goout.net/cs/jine-akce/3-2-1-jedem/qmnub/#"T":"2017-03-15T20:00:00"
```

The problem is that [the W3C validator is not happy about it](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fgoout.net%2Fcs%2Flistky%2F3-2-1-jedem-impro-talk-show-s-cestovatelem-danem-pribanem%2Fvyy%2F).

All the browsers handle the URL well, so I wonder if the validator is too strict or my URL is wrongly escaped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotes are not allowed in the fragment part of a URL, so you have to percent-encode it with `%22`:

```
https://goout.net/cs/jine-akce/3-2-1-jedem-impro-talk-show-s-cestovatelem-danem-pribanem/qmnub/#%22T%22:%222017-03-15T20:00:00%22
```

List of valid characters in the URL fragment part: [List of valid characters for the fragment identifier in an URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849756/list-of-valid-characters-for-the-fragment-identifier-in-an-url#2849800)