# Can I put unencoded slash in url hash?

Tags: java, url

I have a single page web app, I thought it would be a good idea to put some additional information for the user in browser url bar (in that case, which site he uses through my app). Something like myapp.com/#site=localhost/test Can I use it unencoded? I mean I know I can, but is it correct and are there any hidden pitfalls with it? Encoding the slash wouldn't look pretty and miss the point.

Comment: As long as you are encoding, I don't see any problem there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, per [RFC-3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), `/` is a valid character in a URL fragment. See [List of valid characters for the fragment identifier in an URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849756/list-of-valid-characters-for-the-fragment-identifier-in-an-url)